# Flutter Renderboxoverflow

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../../Data/Globalvariable.dart' as global;
// import './customexpansionpanel.dart' as ex;

class Districtslayout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DistrictslayoutState createState() => _DistrictslayoutState();
}

class _DistrictslayoutState extends State<Districtslayout> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer(
        builder: (context, global.DistrictModel districtModel, child) {
      return _totalwig(districtModel.district);
    });
  }

  _totalwig(districts) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(children: [
        ...(districts).map(
          (answer) {
            return answer['district_id'] == 1000
                ? Text('Select_Text')
                : ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                        elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(24),
                        fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                            Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 60))),
                    child: Text(
                      answer['district_name'],
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => print(answer['district_id'].toString()),
                  );
          },
        ).toList(),
      ]),
    );
  }

  // _createwig(districts) {
  //   List<Widget> columnContent = [];
  //   for (dynamic dis in districts) {
  //     columnContent.add(
  //       ListTile(
  //         title: dis['district_id']==1000?Text('Select State'):ElevatedButton(
  //           onPressed: ()=>print(dis['district_id']),
  //           child: Text(
  //             dis['district_name'],
  //             style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
  //           ),
  //         ),
  //       ),
  //     );
  //   }
  //   return columnContent;
  // }
}
```

Here I am getting an error of renderbox overflow even though i have wrapped column into SingleChildScrollView in my widget tree i have a sizedbox then a custom widget then a sizedbox then a singlechildscrollview then column
I hope this is sufficient if you want any code you can just comment and i will update the code

```
import 'package:cowin_slot_tracker/Data/styles/expansionbutton.dart';

import '../../src/By_District/states.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './districts.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../../Data/Globalvariable.dart' as global;

class DistrictHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => DistrictHomeState();
}

class DistrictHomeState extends State<DistrictHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 120)
                // color: Colors.white.withOpacity(1),
                ),
            Divider(
              thickness: 2,
            ),
            Text("hey"),
          ],
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => global.DistrictModel(),
          child: Consumer(
              builder: (context, global.DistrictModel pinModel, child) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                 SizedBox(height: 60, child: StateMenu()),
                 SizedBox(
                    child: ExpnButton(
                  wiget: Districtslayout(),
                  hint: 'Select Districts',
                )),
              ],
            );
          }),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have tried using flexible outside singlechildscrollview yet the problem persists

Comment: Can you include parent widgets tree pattern or this is the only widget on page?

Comment: Alright I can do that

Comment: I have added the whole widget tree for reference as i think the problem is with widget tree only

Answer (score 0):

wrap`SingleChildScrollView` with `Expanded`, like

```
  Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
```

does it solve in your case?

Comment: No it does not i have tried the same with Flexible

Comment: Can you provide us a simple widget that will reproduce these errors, I tried using `Stack<Column<SingleChildScrollView<Column>>>` then found the bottom overflow, after using `Expanded` it solves here.

Comment: So Are you asking for the code of the custom button i made?